# Mask entity field before sending to UI from Spring Rest

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

we are using spring rest which returns course entity object to UI. UI modify course object and update course object. here we don't want to show the URL field to a user who is modifying that course object. so I want to mask that single field. can you please suggest the best way to modify that

Comment: Maybe you should use a [data-transfer object (DTO)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object) instead of passing an entity directly to UI.  In the DTO you may completely exclude sensitive field(s) or modify them as necessary.

Answer (score 1):

- Bring only relevant data from database - Check Spring Data REST `Projection` facility. It allows bringing a subset of entity data and automatically expose it.
- Suppress entity data serialization - If you need to bring entity data but *never* expose it, a simple `@JsonIgnore` annotation on field may be used.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually, we implemented this. instead of masking, we decided don't want to send that field to UI by @JsonIgnore. But that failed while updating the object. so added @jsonIgnore only got getter method and add @JsonProperty(access = Access.WRITE_ONLY) to the field. so instead of masking we are not sending the field to UI and allow the field to write by customization of @jsonIgnore